# SNMP agent on embedded device, No such object available on this agent at this OID

Tags: router, snmp, linux, docsis

SNMP agent on an embedded device. When I query SNMP device for the particular private enterprise OID object, it says "No such object available on this agent at this OID".

snmpget -v2c -c public 10.x.x.x .1.3.6.1.4.1.8595..

These objects are included in MTA config file. So my assumption was that these private OIDs objects are present in the system, but they may not be available for viewing with default "public" community string, *or* they are shown via SNMP version **v3c** access, *or* some more reasons. So first I  should check SNMP agent code built into that device, does it actually contain that private MIBs? If it contains, then it should be accessible via SNMP query, is it correct? Or even it exist on the SNMP agent, it may not be accessible with SNMP query?

Comment: did you tried to check using snmpwalk? in SNMP V2 if the OID available on the agent it should be accessible .

Comment: snmpwalk v2c did not show these OIDs.

Comment: Then they are not exist.may be they are not available on your version of the switch IOS

Comment: Not in cisco switch, in MTA device. I will check the SNMP agent.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2):

Whenever I face issues with an OID not being found, I always use the `snmpwalk` command, in order to see what the devices do respond to:

```
snmpwalk -v 2c -c public 10.x.x.x
```

Comment: as I noted, snmpwalk -v2c does not show these OIDs. As I think this issue is somehow related with SNMPv3 access.

Comment: So, are you not able to make use of the -v3 at the bottom on the page : https://syslogwatcher.com/cmd-tools/snmp-walk/

Comment: Not so easy, not working. Apart from common SNMPv3 parameters, also _v3 Access_ need be installed, set _View_, not sure was these performed at compile time.

Answer (score 1):

The issue may be authorization related.

Many SNMP agents, like Linux CentOS snmpd daemon for example, have the **view** object in order give authorization to branches of the OID tree.

Named views can represent the entire OID tree (example, "all" `.1`) or some subtree (example, "systemview" `.1.3.6.1.2.1.1`).

Once named views are in place, rules can be defined to allow some kind of access (read, r/w) using a security model among SNMP v1, v2c and v3.

If that device runs a linux kernel and net-snmpd agent, access to the whole OID tree could require another security model (e.g. v3), or an access-list definition between community and view.